# Joining to another table with a lag function / invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is the first time that I have used the LAG function.  I understand how it works on a simple example but I need to join to 2 other tables to to get the results that I'm looking for.  The end result will be 1 row where the prevamount field contains the pdr.depr value for accounting period 10

I'm getting an error (invalid identifier on the CF_SEQNO field) when I try to run this sql.  Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help.

```
select
pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT,
pdr.DEPTID,
pdr.ASSET_ID,
pdr.DEPR,
pa.DESCR,
pdr.ACCOUNT_AD, 
pdl.ACCOUNT,
pdl.JOURNAL_ID,
pdl.JOURNAL_DATE,
pdr.FISCAL_YEAR,
pdr.accounting_period

FROM    (select  lag(pdr.depr) over (
                    partition by pdr.deptid
                    order by pdr.fiscal_year, pdr.accounting_period) as prevamount,
                pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT,
                pdr.DEPTID,
                pdr.ASSET_ID,
                pdr.DEPR as curramt,
                pdr.ACCOUNT_AD, 
                pdr.FISCAL_YEAR,
                pdr.accounting_period

       from    ps_depr_rpt pdr )

INNER JOIN PS_DIST_LN pdl 
ON pdl.BOOK = pdr.BOOK
AND pdl.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT
--AND pdl.FISCAL_YEAR = pdr.FISCAL_YEAR
--AND pdl.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
AND pdl.ASSET_ID = pdr.ASSET_ID
AND pdl.CF_SEQNO = pdr.CF_SEQNO

INNER JOIN PS_ASSET pa 
ON pa.ASSET_ID = pdl.ASSET_ID
AND pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdl.BUSINESS_UNIT

WHERE
pdr.business_unit = 'A0465'
AND pdr.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
AND pdr.fiscal_year = 2014
AND pdr.accounting_period = 11
AND pdl.DISTRIBUTION_TYPE = 'DE'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a table alias on the subquery:

```
FROM    (select  lag(pdr.depr) over (
                    partition by pdr.deptid
                    order by pdr.fiscal_year, pdr.accounting_period) as prevamount,
                pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT,
                pdr.DEPTID,
                pdr.ASSET_ID,
                pdr.DEPR as curramt,
                pdr.ACCOUNT_AD, 
                pdr.FISCAL_YEAR,
                pdr.accounting_period

       from    ps_depr_rpt pdr ) pdr
---------------------------------^
```